# Accessor and Mutator Methods in Dexterity

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm beginner user of dexterity (about 2 days now). I'm trying to migrate my old content type to dextertiy content in process of migrating website.

Schema defination in classic archetype is like

```
TextField('script',
          searchable=0,
          mutator="write",
          accessor="__call__",
          edit_accessor="document_src",
          widget=TextAreaWidget(label="Page Template script",rows=40,cols=40),
```

How can I redefine in dexterity ? I'm upgrading from Plone 252 to Plone 412.

Regards,

Comment: Are you sure you need an accessor?  One of the points of Dexterity is to remove the needs for expliit or generated accessor/mutator code.   If you need a method to provide a field value, you can use a Python property or descriptor (on a custom content class) to abstract your method behind a field/attribute/property interface for set/get.

Comment: Umm. I'm not sure about using these methods. I'm going through this dexterity-developer-manual.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/… but it's not clear to me

Comment: I'm trying to create content type that have field which takes Page Templates code and render in my custom view. that's why I was using accessor and mutator in my old archetype to use zpt methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create a new Dexterity content type from scratch and completely rewrite your Archetype's Schema to a new schema that inherits from plone.directives.form and with the field types form zope.schema.

For more information, see here:
http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/schema-driven-types/referencemanual-all-pages

For example, your Archetype's schema field declaration, will look like something like this in Dexterity:

```
script = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Page Template Script"),
    )
```

Dexterity content types don't get automatic accessors and mutators like Archetypes content types. Instead, you just access the schema field as if it's an attribute.

For example:

```
script = myfolder.script
```

If you want to create the same accessors and mutator (like you specified in the Archetypes field), you'll have to create them manually on your Dexterity class.

For example, something like:

```
class MyFolder(dexterity.Container):
    """ """
    grok.implements(IMyFolderSchema)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.script

    def edit_accessor(self):
        return self.script

    def write(self, value):
        self.script = value
```